# Java ProcessBuilder with multiple params with spaces

Tags: java, parameters, cmd, space, processbuilder

I know that there is a lot of solved questions regarding executing processes from java.But I am unable to solve my problem using answers provided.
I am trying go create postgresql database backup from java application. I use following code

```
        //ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"cmd","/c","D:/PostgreSQL 8.2/bin/pg_dump.exe","-U","usr","-i","-h","localhost","-p","5432","-F","c","-b","-f","D:/backup test/backups/test_27-1-2013_210.backup", "test"});
        //ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"cmd","/c","D:\\PostgreSQL 8.2\\bin\\pg_dump.exe","-U","usr","-i","-h","localhost","-p","5432","-F","c","-b","-f","D:\\backup test\\backups\\test_27-1-2013_210.backup", "test"});
        ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"cmd","/c","\"D:\\PostgreSQL 8.2\\bin\\pg_dump.exe\"","-U","usr","-i","-h","localhost","-p","5432","-F","c","-b","-f","\"D:\\backup test\\backups\\test_27-1-2013_210.backup\"", "test"});
        Map<String, String> env = probuilder.environment();
        env.put("PGPASSWORD", "mypass");

        final Process process = probuilder.start();
```

After executing above code i get following error:
`D:\PostgreSQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Problem occures only when path to backup file contains spaces otherwise backup is created.
I have tried to use both slash and backslash in the file path and I quoted file path but i get the same error every time. Command can be executed from command prompt.

What I am doing wrong. Is there some limitations regarding number of parameters with spaces in ProcessBuilder.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `pg_dump.exe` is an exe (not a .bat) you don't need the `cmd` at all, and it is probably causing more problems than it solves.  Just call the `exe` directly, and remove the extra set of quotes around the file paths:

```
new String[]{"D:\\PostgreSQL 8.2\\bin\\pg_dump.exe","-U","usr","-i",
  "-h","localhost","-p","5432","-F","c","-b",
  "-f","D:\\backup test\\backups\\test_27-1-2013_210.backup", "test"}
```

Comment: You are the men. This caused the problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user2115093 thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you get an answer that solves your problem it's good manners to _accept_ it by clicking on the tick mark to the left.  Building a track record of accepting good answers is the way to encourage more people to help with your future questions.

Comment: I planned to do that but I could't find at first look where do I need to click. Thanks again