# Can't remove/install tomcat service with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, tomcat, processbuilder

This command **works** via batch-file:

`c:\tomcat\bin\tomcat7.exe //DS//"A TestService"`

The same statement doesn't work with ProcessBuilder:

```
 public static void removeService() throws Exception
 {
     String tomcatBinPath = "c:\\tomcat\\bin";
     File binFolder = new File(tomcatBinPath);
     String[] parms= new String[4];
     parms[0] = "cmd";
     parms[1] = "/c";
     parms[2] = tomcatBinPath + "\\tomcat7.exe";
     parms[3] = "//DS//\"A TestService\"";
     ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(parms);
     ProcessBuilder newPb = pb.directory(binFolder);
     newPb = newPb.redirectErrorStream(true);
     Process proc = newPb.start();
     int result = proc.waitFor();
     System.out.println(result);
 }
```

The result is always `9` and the service is **not** removed.

**NOTE:**
The problem seems to be the SPACE/BLANK inside the service-name.
I have no problems with ProcessBuilder if the service-name contains no SPACES/BLANKS!


**Question:**
How to use ProcessBuilder in such a case (SPACES/BLANKS in service-name)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java ProcessBuilder with multiple params with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111517/java-processbuilder-with-multiple-params-with-spaces)